# How can I get SPSS line chart to intersect graph at 0,0?

Tags: time, graph, statistics, time-series, spss

I need to get the attached line graph to go through the chart at (0, 0) (x, y) in SPSS. I have edited the chart with red to denote what I want the graph to look like.

Does anyone know how to do this?

For the variables, I have the time variable (x-axis) type as "Date" and measure as "Scale."

[SPSS Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcWEe.png)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Add 0, 0 Point to Data & Variable View

Navigate to "Variable View" and make sure both variables are set to "Scale" for "Measure."

To X and Y data, add a point for 0, 0.

### 2. Change Graph to Scatter Plot

Graphs > Legacy Dialogs > Scatter/Dot > Simple Scatter > Define > Enter X and Y variables > Click "Ok"

### 3. Edit Axes in Chart Editor

In the output file, double click the chart to activate the "Chart Editor" window.

Double click the Y-axis to bring up the "Properties" window and edit lower and upper margins.

[Y-axis > Properties > Scale > Lower Margin = 0, Upper Margin =0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qfqo.png)

Double click the X-axis to bring up the "Properties" window and edit lower and upper margins.

[X-axis > Properties > Scale > Lower Margin = 0, Upper Margin = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUQTb.png)

### 4. Add a Line

In the "Chart Editor" window, double click the points on the graph to bring up the "Properties" window.

In the properties window: Variables > Interpolation Line

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z6nj.png)